# Generating numbers outside of my range C++ (way too large)

Tags: c++

I decided for fun to try and make a simple program that "sort of" simulates blackjack in a dumbed down way. It's basically done, except for the fact that the randomly generated numbers are WAY too large. I don't care about the bias srand/rand has (for now) I just want to get it working properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int genRandInt (int low, int high) {
    int randnum = low + (rand() % (high - low + 1));
    return randnum;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int computerScore;
    int score;
    int card;

    while (int playAgain = 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter 0 to hold or 1 to hit: ";
        int play;
        cin >> play;

        if (play == 0)
        {
             computerScore = genRandInt(1, 31);

             if (score < computerScore)
             {
                 cout << "Your score is " << score << " and the computer's score is " << computerScore << "! You lose.\n";
             }

             if (score > 21)
             {
                 cout << "Your score is " << score << " which is greater than 21. Bust!\n";
             }

             if (score > computerScore && score <= 21)
             {
                 cout << "Your score is " << score << " and the computer's score is " << computerScore << "! You win!\n";
             }

             cout << "Would you like to play again? 1 for yes, 0 for no. : ";
             cin >> playAgain;
        }


        if (play == 1)
        {
            card = genRandInt(1, 11);
            score = score + card;
            cout << "Your score is: " << score << "\n";
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `while (int playAgain = 1)`  Shouldn't this be `playAgain == 1`?

Comment: A simple program shows that it isn't the random numbers or your `getRandInt` function: http://ideone.com/QhyNAQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `int score;` uninitialized in

```
if (score < computerScore)
```

or

```
score = score + card;
```

depending on the `if(play == 0)` or `if(play == 1)` condition.

It happens to have some junk as its memory content, **the compiler does not initializes to zero for you**. In fact, it is undefined behaviour to use un-initialized variables. Initialize it before the first usage, preferable in the definition itself,

```
int score = 0;
```

Also, compile with warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra` for g++/clang++), since the compiler will easily warn about these mistakes.

Comment: Okay it's fixed now, thanks! Could you explain what your last sentence meant? I have no idea how to set warnings for compiling.

Comment: @CodyHayes if some answer helped solving your problem, you should accept it. If you use `g++`, you can compile your program like `g++ -Wall -Wextra program.cpp -o program`, i.e. can add warning flags so the compiler spits out all kinds of useful warnings, like the one about using un-initialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this and seeing if you have the same issues. I just added some print statements to try and debug it, and it stopped showing me really big numbers..

```
     EDIT:
//ADD
    int score = 0;
//

                if (play == 1)
                {
                    cout << "printing in the PLAY = 1 "<< score << endl;
                    card = genRandInt(1, 11);
                    score = score + card;
                    cout << "Your score is: " << score << "\n";
                }
```

Comment: Ah it's definitely the "int score" issue. I printed it out in the  if (play == 1) statement and I think Xcode initialized it for me so the issue went away.